# Android ListAdapter not refreshing immediately after delete

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

In my android application, I have a list in fragment using an adapter which extends ArrayAdapter. Whenever you hold a row item for long you can delete that row by clicking Yes on an alert-dialogue. But when you click Yes, last row seems to be deleted. When you close that fragment and come back on it then the view is fine with proper row deleted. After debugging for so many days I am unable to fix this.Can anyone please figure out whats wrong ?
Thanks in advance.

**AdapterClass**

```
public class DuasListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    // class variables
        private final Context context;// to save context
        private final List<String> duas;// to save list of stores
        LayoutInflater inflater;// so save layout inflater for the view

        public DuasListAdapter(Context ctx, List<String> duasList) {

            super(ctx, R.layout.adapter_list_duas, duasList);
            context = ctx;// save context
            duas = duasList;// save list of stores
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);// save inflater layout
        }



    @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



            ViewHolder holder;
            // if view is not loaded
            if (!(convertView instanceof View)) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_list_duas, parent, false);
                // load the view from holder class
                holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
                // set the tag for future use
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            // if view is loaded
            else
                // get view from tag
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

            holder.duaIndex = position;

convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                        final View view = v;
                        DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                switch (which) {
                                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
                                        int index = holder.duaIndex;
                                        ((MainActivity) context).removeItemFromList(index);
                                        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        break;

                                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                        // No button clicked
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        };

                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                        builder.setMessage("Delete Dua from Favorites?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener).setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();

                        return false;
                    }
                });
return convertView;
        }
```

**ListFragment**

```
public void removeItemFromList(int index) {
        String verses = new SharedPreferencesSupplication().read(SingletonClass.keyListOfVerses, "a1");
        String[] versesList = verses.split(",");
        String identifier = versesList[index];
        new FavoriteDuas().removeDua(identifier);
        updatedData();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        lvDuaas.setAdapter(duasAdapter);
        updatedData();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        lvDuaas.setAdapter(duasAdapter);
        updatedData();
        super.onPause();
    }

    public void updatedData() {
        boolean keyIsFavSel = new SharedPreferencesSupplication().read(SingletonClass.keyIsFavSelected, false);
        if (keyIsFavSel)
            new SharedPreferencesSupplication().save(SingletonClass.keyListOfVerses, new SharedPreferencesSupplication().read(SingletonClass.keyFavVerses, "a1"));
        String verses = new SharedPreferencesSupplication().read(SingletonClass.keyListOfVerses, "a1");
        String[] versesList = verses.split(",");
        ArrayList<String> duas = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < versesList.length; i++) {
            if (versesList[i].length() > 0)
                duas.add(versesList[i]);
        }

        duasAdapter.clear();

        if (duas.size() > 0) {

            for (String object : duas) {

                duasAdapter.insert(object, duasAdapter.getCount());
            }
        }

        duasAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }
```

**Delete-Method**

```
public void removeDua(String duaIdentifier) {
        String verses = new SharedPreferencesSupplication().read(SingletonClass.keyFavVerses, "");
        String[] versesList = verses.split(",");
        int indexFound = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < versesList.length; i++) {
            if (versesList[i].equals(duaIdentifier)) {
                indexFound = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (indexFound >= 0) {
            verses = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < versesList.length; i++) {
                if (indexFound != i) {
                    if (verses.isEmpty())
                        verses = versesList[i];
                    else
                        verses = verses + "," + versesList[i];
                }
            }
            new SharedPreferencesSupplication().save(SingletonClass.keyFavVerses, verses);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to re-instantiate the duasAdapter

```
duasAdapter = new DuasListAdapter(your_context_here, duas);
```

instead of

```
duasAdapter.clear();

            if (duas.size() > 0) {

                for (String object : duas) {

                    duasAdapter.insert(object, duasAdapter.getCount());
                }
            }

            duasAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code to verify that the list from sp is updated or not?

Comment: Yes, I have many a times, the list is being updated properly.

Answer (score 0):

You are using setOnLongClickListener() on your view, use setOnItemLongClickListener() instead.

Comment: No such  method found : setOnItemLongClickListener() for convertView. Only convertView.setOnLongClickListener() is accessible.

Comment: Use setOnItemLongClickListener() on your listview that you are populating using the array adapter.